# Confusion with simple probability concepts

Tags: probability

There is a problem which goes, there are 6 red balls and $4$ green balls and a sample of $7$ balls are chosen.

Show that the probability such that all the balls chosen are red.

My answer is $0$, because there are only $6$ red balls, how can we choose $7$ sample balls when there are only $6$ red balls?

Is this correct?

Comment: With replacement or without?

Comment: "Show that the probability such that all the balls chosen are red." That should read "Find the probability that all the balls chosen are red. "

Answer (score 2):

Yup, that's correct. Since it's  impossible for all $7$ balls to be red - because there aren't $7$ or more red balls to begin with - the probability of that would be $0$.

Comment: Thank you I guess I was just over thinking this.

Comment: lol that's perfectly normal, I'm the same way with probability. But at least it shows you're thinking about the material, which is a good thing. :P